# Another null set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If a sequence $\{A_n\}$ of subsets of $X$ satisfies $\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\mu ({A_n}) < \infty } $, then show that the set

$$E=\{x\in X: x \,\,\text{belongs to}\,\,A_n \,\,\text{for infinitely many}\,\,n \}$$

is a null set.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi(x) = \sum_n 1_{A_n}(x)$. Then you see that $\phi(x) = \infty$ iff $x \in A_n$ infinitely often.

Monotone convergence gives $\int \phi = \sum_n \int 1_{A_n} = \sum_n \mu A_n < \infty$, hence we must have that $\phi(x)$ is finite for ae. $x$ [$\mu$].
That is, $E=\{x | \phi(x)=\infty \}$ is a null set.

**Addendum**: Here 's an 'elementary' proof (although I think the above is far more intuitive):

Note that $E = \cap_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{k = n}^\infty A_k$, so, in particular, we have $E \subset \cup_{k = n}^\infty A_k$ for all $n$. Hence
$\mu E \le \sum_{k = n}^\infty \mu A_k$ for all $n$. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = n}^\infty \mu A_k = 0$, we have $\mu E = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. But please solve using set and usless functions!!!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: only use elementary knowledge from OUTER MEASURES AND MEASURABLE SETS.
my: Set ${E_n} = \bigcup\limits_{i = n}^\infty  {{A_i}} $ and note that $E \subseteq {E_n}$. (How to continue?)

Comment: @MathMan Can you give an upper bound for $\mu(E_n)$?

Comment: yes, @DanielFischer.We have $\mu ({E_n}) \le \sum\nolimits_{i = n}^\infty  {\mu ({A_i})} $

Comment: Is this true?
$$0 \le \mu (E) \le \mu ({E_n}) \le \sum\nolimits_{i = n}^\infty  {\mu ({A_i})}  \to 0$$

Comment: Both proofs are awesome. Can I vote you double?